# I have a long form for adding a vehicle in my RN app, it has like 12 fields to add the vehicle which is contained in a modal, how can I improve this?

Tags: react-native, user-interface

the 12 fields are text fields and they are all displayed one under another, is there any better approach for that I think the modal is too crowded, and it will act weird with keyboard avoiding behaviors.

ps: instead of thumbing the question down please suggest to me how can I make it clearer
Thanks

I didnt try anything to enhance so far, I think it needs to go in steps, instead of having it in one big blob
[image: my form]

Comment: can you provide which type of modal UI you have expecting

Comment: @VhoraAbdulrauf i just made an edit